# Random uppercase letter not working

Tags: c#

I want to make a random "password" generator that generates a length of different letters. You input the length and it make length random characters. I also want some random letters to be capitalized. I have a variable rndCap which to 1 or 2. The if will turn it into a capital letter if rndCap == 2, if not, it does nothing. The answer is all of the characters combined. When I execute, the numbers are all lowercase. Everything works except for it randomly capitalizing a character.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

string[] alphabet = new string[27];

alphabet[1] = "a";
alphabet[2] = "b";
alphabet[3] = "c";
alphabet[4] = "d";
alphabet[5] = "e";
alphabet[6] = "f";
alphabet[7] = "g";
alphabet[8] = "h";
alphabet[9] = "i";
alphabet[10] = "j";
alphabet[11] = "k";
alphabet[12] = "l";
alphabet[13] = "m";
alphabet[14] = "n";
alphabet[15] = "o";
alphabet[16] = "p";
alphabet[17] = "q";
alphabet[18] = "r";
alphabet[19] = "s";
alphabet[20] = "t";
alphabet[21] = "u";
alphabet[22] = "v";
alphabet[23] = "w";
alphabet[24] = "x";
alphabet[25] = "y";
alphabet[26] = "z";

string answer = "";
int length = Convert.ToInt32(lengthTextBox.Text);
int rndCap;
int rndLetter;

for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
{
    rndCap = rnd.Next(1, 3);
    rndLetter = rnd.Next(1, 27);
    string tempMem = alphabet[rndLetter];

    if (rndCap == 2)
    {
        tempMem.ToUpper();
    }
    answer = answer + tempMem;
}

passwordTextBox.Text = answer;
```

Comment: Why not just put capital letters in your alphabet array?

Comment: Why do you create an array of size `27` and then index from `1-26`? You should just create an array of size `26` then index from `0-25`. Something tells me you need to review the basics...

Comment: A suggestion: do char[] array = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();

Comment: What are the chances that `if` doesn't work compared to the chances that you made a simple error? :)

Comment: Do not use a standart Random for password generation! It is predictable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the IF is working :)

[`String.ToUpper()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed.aspx) however doesn't change the string at hand to uppercase, but returns it as the result. You have to assign the value. What you wanted is probably this:

```
tempMem = tempMem.ToUpper();
```

Also, a rule to follow: **Always bear in mind, that the 
*encoding, the culture and the locale* can be different than that of your current one.**

Even though in this case, we are only using "harmless-looking" ASCII characters, but to translate this into practice with uppercasing strings:

- use the [ToUpper(CultureInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24kc78ka.aspx) to specify a culture
- use the [ToUpperInvariant()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24kc78ka.aspx) to use the "invariant culture" instead of the default one

As Jeppe noted: in the Turkish locale, i is uppercased to a character different from I - introducing unwanted consequences.

Comment: String.ToUpperInvariant() would probably be better for this.

Comment: @Dunbar yep, defaults don't play when dealing with localization and encoding...

Comment: To give the usual example, `"i".ToUpper(new CultureInfo("tr-TR")) != "I"`, meaning that with some culture, namely "Turkish (Turkey)", saying `ToUpper` on an Ascii char gives a non-Ascii char.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen sadly, I reached the daily comment upvote limit, but thanks nonetheless for the useful comment!

Comment: More precisely, `"i".ToUpper(new CultureInfo("tr-TR")) == "İ"` and `"İ" != "I"`. See [Wikipedia on İ/i versus I/ı](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I).

Answer (score 3):

string is `immutable` so you need to assign it again

```
tempMem = tempMem.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 1):

You call ToUpper, but don't assign the value:

```
tempMem = tempMem.ToUpper()
```

Maybe this code is in general more elegant:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random cRandom = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        string answer = "";
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(6);
        int rndCap;
        int rndLetter;

        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
        {

            rndCap = cRandom.Next(1, 3);

            rndLetter = cRandom.Next(0, 26);

            char tempMem = (char)('a' + rndLetter);
            string c2 = tempMem.ToString();
            if (rndCap == 2)
            {

               c2 = tempMem.ToString().ToUpper();

            }

            answer = answer + c2;

        }
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
tempMem = tempMem.ToUpper();
```

as `ToUpper()` doesn't make uppercasing to string it is invoked on, it returns copy of this string with all letters uppercased.

Answer (score 0):

`ToUpper()` is a method that returns an uppercase string, so you need to assign the value of tempMem to that value:

```
tempMem = tempMem.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are simpler ways to perform what you want to achieve.  Have a look at this code;

```
        var lowerchar = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var upperchar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var numbers = "0123456789";
        var random = new Random();

        var result = new string(
            Enumerable.Repeat(lowerchar, 3)
                      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                      .ToArray());

        result += new string(
            Enumerable.Repeat(upperchar, 3)
                      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                      .ToArray());

         result += new string(
            Enumerable.Repeat(numbers, 2)
                      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                      .ToArray());

        random = new Random();

        string password = new string(result.ToCharArray().OrderBy(s => random.Next().ToArray());
```

Comment: Your shuffling is not properly done.  You're choosing a random boolean value, which is insufficient entropy for the shuffle.  You'll end up with a significant collision rate (in fact ~n/2 collisions) and since this is a stable sort, it means the numbers will be nearer the end and the lower case numbers nearer the start.  Instead just select a random int and order on *that*, which gives you *much* lower odds at collisions.

Comment: Can you give me a example of what you mean or modify my answer ?

Comment: also, that can be further simplified http://ideone.com/XHNlkX

Answer (score 0):

All string manipulations returns the new string and not modifying the original since string is imutable.
Modify it like that: tempMem = tempMem.ToUpper();